# Show all fields inside a Power apps form in a Vertical layout of 1 column instead of 3 columns on small screen sizes (mobile screens),

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to make my Power Apps standalone have a responsive design similar to Bootstrap effect. where if we have a form with 3 columns, as follow:

[image]

Now if we view this form using Power Apps mobile app or using mobile web, I want to show the fields dynamically in one column as follow:

[image]

So is this possible? I hope so.

Here is my current settings for the Power Apps:

The form:

[image]

Display settings of app:

[image]

Any advice please? my application will be accessed mainly using 3 devices/screen:

1. Desktops & Laptops
2. Mobile phones (mobile app + mobile web)
3. pads & tablets

Comment: Do you want to see 1 column layout for desktop/tablet as well, or just mobile devices?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap
 Desktop 3 columns >> mobile 1 column

Comment: Check my answer given below.

Comment: @GaneshSanap ...  but where i can add the formula ? inside which property? screen or form?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value for "Columns" property given under "Snap to columns" property (which allows number value) based on the `ScreenSize`:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Screen sizes and breakpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/create-responsive-layout#screen-sizes-and-breakpoints)

You can simply use `Parent.Size` for "Columns" property given under "Snap to columns" property which will show 1 column for mobile devices, 4 columns for desktop as shown in above table **OR** you can build formula like below as per your requirements:

**Example**: Show 1 column layout for mobile devices & show 3 columns layout for all other device sizes.

```
If(ScreenName.Size = ScreenSize.Small, 1, 3)
```

**Other references**:

1. [Create Responsive Power Apps from SharePoint list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uABDL7_EDCs)

Comment: but where i can add the formula ? inside which property? screen or form?

Comment: Add this formula in "Snap to columns" property of form control.

Comment: Snap to column is a checkbox not a property that allow adding formulas

Comment: Write this formula for "Columns" property given under "Snap to columns" property, which allows number value. Currently it is set to `3` in the image you shared in your question.

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: columns propeorty only allow selecting number does not allow formulas